# SharePoint Online sub-links levels

Tags: sharepoint-online

In SharePoint Online, can i somehow have more then 2 sublevels on the left sidebar and the header menu?

I found a guide saying that i can Edit master.page, change MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="0" to MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3" for id="V4QuickLaunchMenu".

Where is this file located?

I have connected to domain-my.sharepoint.com in sharepoint designer 2013 but i cant find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is in Master pages-> seatle.master, open it in advanced mode.

[image]

[image]